# How can I optimise this for loop which creates a list of dicts?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, parallel-processing

I have the following loop which makes ~3 million iterations.

```
json_data = []
for customer_id in tqdm(dataset["customer_id"].unique()):
    customer_data = dataset[dataset["customer_id"] == customer_id]
    label = customer_data.iloc[0]["label"]
    phone_number = customer_data.iloc[0]["phone_number"]
    email_address = customer_data.iloc[0]["email_address"]
    device_ids = customer_data["device_id"].unique()
    json_data.append(
        {
            "uid": f"_:{int(customer_id)}",
            "customer_id": int(customer_id),  # int64 -> int
            "label": label,
            "has_phone_number": [
                {"uid": f"_:{phone_number}", "phone_number": phone_number}
            ],
            "has_email_address": [
                {"uid": f"_:{email_address}", "email_address": email_address}
            ],
            "has_device_id": [
                {"uid": f"_:{device_id}", "device_id": device_id}
                for device_id in device_ids
            ],
        }
    )
```

What would be the best way to optimise this? Would a comprehension do any better? I have also thought about parallelising it using joblib. Are there any other recommended/better ways?

Comment: Are you asking because it is too slow? The first line in the loop seems suspicious to me - I don’t understand the details, but iterating over all unique customer ids and then for each one again finding all customers with that id seems wasteful. Why not just iterate over all customers directly and using their id as needed in the loop?

Comment: Yes, it is slow. According to `tqdm` it will take upwards of 5 hours. There can be many rows in `dataset` for each `customer_id` and all of these rows are needed for the line `device_ids = customer_data["device_id"].unique()`

Comment: What does `.iloc[0]` mean?

Comment: It just selects the first row from a `pandas` DataFrame, because for each `customer_id`, all the rows have the same `label`, `phone_number` and `email_address`, but different `device_id`s.

Comment: I guess you should be using something like `dataset.groupby('customer_id')`, but I don’t know enough Pandas to tell you how.

Answer (score 1):

Please use https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler to check which are the slow lines.

Often the bottleneck is not where you think it is.

One thing that you could tweak is to look up say 100 customer_ids at once and process in chunks. That often reduces overhead.

Then you can put a good balance to it, e.g. look up in chunks of 1000 and use a shared list with multiprocessing to append the JSON. Once you publish the results of line_profiler we can discuss on how to do it.